# Get Drive name of the SmartCard

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am writing a java smart card application in windows MFC. How do i find the drive name( name display in  "My Computer") of the connected smart card.  For eg. once i connect the smart card(even though it a smart card, it will work as memory card ) it will come as "** Removable Disk(F:)**" . I am able to connect to smart card using SCardConnect function. from the handle return from SCardConnect function, can i get the drive name .

Or is there any way to find out whether a particular drive is smart card. ie. we can easily find out the removable disks in the machine and from that is it possible to find out whether its a smart card or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your idea is too bad. I have two smart card readers, first - internal usb reader and Dell Smart Card Keyboard. In my application I tested many Smart Cards and never see they acts as Removable Disk.

Comment: I am talking about java smard card which can be used as crypto card and memory card in mobiles. In mobile it will act as memory card but for mobile applications it will also act as java smart card also. I am developing applications for android phone using smart card. In system it will detect as memory card. Hope u are talking about some other type smart card

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written code to enumerate SmartCard devices, in C; here is the code I use;

Cheers,
Con

```
int findDevice(){
hContext = NULL;

log("\nSearching for the following device: XXX eKrypto Pinpad\n");

//Get a context to the resource manager 
lReturn = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER,NULL,NULL,&hContext);
log("Context established.\n");
if(lReturn != SCARD_S_SUCCESS){
  logBytes("SCardEstablishContext failed with error: ", (byte *)&lReturn, sizeof(LONG));
  return 0;
}

contextEstablished = true;

//Get the readers list
DWORD chReaders = 250;
lReturn = SCardListReaders(hContext,NULL,readerNames,&chReaders);
log("Reader List obtained.\n");
if(lReturn != SCARD_S_SUCCESS){
    logBytes("  SCardListReaders failed with error: \n", (byte *)&lReturn, sizeof(LONG));
    return 0;
}

//Search for device
char *pReaders = readerNames;
log(pReaders);
while(strlen(pReaders) != 0 && deviceFound == false){
    if(!memcmp(pReaders, "ETS eKrypto Pinpad", 18)){
        deviceFound = true;
        memcpy(currentReader, pReaders, strlen(pReaders));
    }
    pReaders += strlen (pReaders)+1;
}
if(deviceFound == false){
    log("  Specified ETS device not found\n");
    return 0;
}

log("  Successful\n");
return 1;
}
```